# dropwizard version migration and DI

Tags: dropwizard

I've run to some issues trying to migrate dropwizard from 1.2 to 2.0.24 (and 2.0.25) related to DI, wondering if someone has had same issues or any ideas.

We have one application,

```
public class Account extends Application<AccountConfiguration> {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Account().run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<Configuration> bootstrap) {
        bootstrap.addBundle(new DropwizardBundle<>());
    }

    @Override
    public void run(AccountConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception { 
        ...
        environment.jersey().register(new SessionResource(authenticationService));
    }
}
```

The DropWizardBundle class binds an instance to a class:

```
public void run(AccountConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {
    environment.jersey().register(new AbstractBinder() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(configuration.getResponder()).to(Responder.class);
        }
    });
```

And the SessionResource looks like

```
@Path("/sessions")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "application/v1+json"})
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Timed
public class SessionResource {
    @Inject
    private Responder responder;
    private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;
    
    @POST / @GET methods
}
```

The current code, in Dropwizard 1.2 is running and Responder is injected. Switching to 2.0.24/25 Responder is null. I am wondering if I missed something in the migration..

Comment: What is `configuration.getResponder()`? Is it an instance or a class? Please, provide field declaration

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is working the way you intended (or the way you are think it is) in version1.X for you. I do not know what `configuration.getResponder()` is returning so I can't really test your case. I found for resource classes using DI, a lot of problems I see people face can be solved by registering the class and allow the H2K instantiate the resources for you.

`environment.jersey().register(SessionResource.class);`

You will have to update how `AuthenticationService` is passed into the resource by registering it to so it can also be injected. The below is an example of registering it as a `AuthenticationService` as a singleton.

```
public void run(AccountConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {
    environment.jersey().register(new AbstractBinder() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
           //Not sure how AuthenticationService is instantiate but this is an example
            bind(new AuthenticationService()).to(AuthenticationServic.class).in(Singleton.class);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ben. My conclusion was the same, the registration of the resources needs to happen using the class for the binds to work, while in dropwizard 1.x it works with class instatiation.